# Proving the validity of a group structure on $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to establish that this binary operation on $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is a group.

> Let $A = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ and define a binary operation by
> $$
> (m_1, n_1) \cdot (m_2, n_2) := (m_1 + n_1, m_2 + n_2).
> $$

It's certainly closed since $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed under addition. I'm stuck at this point. I need to establish associativity: so for every $(a,b), (c,d), (e,f) \in A$, we should have
$$[(a,b) \cdot (c,d)] \cdot (e,f) = (a,b) \cdot [(c,d) \cdot (e,f)].$$
Upon expanding out both sides, I can't figure out how to match them. For the LHS, I get
$$
[(a,b) \cdot (c,d)] \cdot (e,f) = (a + b, c + d) \cdot (e,f) = ((a + b) + (c+d), e + f)
$$
For the RHS, I get
$$
(a,b) \cdot [(c,d) \cdot (e,f)] = (a,b) \cdot (c + d, e + f) = (a + b, (c + d) + (e+f)). 
$$

Have I done something wrong here?

Continuing with the verification:

The identity element should be $(0,0)$, which is certainly an element of $A$. Let $(a,b) \in A$. Then
$$
(a,b) \cdot (0,0) = (a + b, 0 + 0) = (a + b, 0), 
$$
which is, of course, not $(a,b)$, so something is wrong again.

Without an identity, I can't figure out how to check inverses.

I'd appreciate any help. My conclusion at this point is that $A$ cannot be a group, but I may have done something wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you have the operation right? You might want $m_1+m_2$ where you have $m_1+n_1$ (with other similar changes). The operation you defined does not make the set into a group - as you observed.

Comment: If you are talking about cross-products, they're are non-associative.

Comment: @EthanBolker This is what the set of lecture notes I'm working through write, but it might have meant component-wise addition. I believe that operation would work.

Comment: With component wise addition you do get a group. With this operation you don't. So either the notes have an error (probably just a typo) in the operation or an error in what you are asked to show.

Answer (score 3):

The identity element need not be $(0,0)$. It should be $(x,y)$ such that, for every $(a,b)$, $(a,b)\cdot(x,y)=(a,b)$ and $(x,y)\cdot(a,b)=(a,b)$.

Take $a=b=1$ and you immediately get a contradiction:
$$
(1,1)\cdot(x,y)=(2,x+y)\ne(1,1)
$$
So the operation lacks an identity and you're finished. No need to check associativity.